# Why when I close a sub-form in a Windows forms Add-in on Revit , it closes the entire add-in?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have a Windows Forms Add-in on Revit using Revit-API and C#. The project contains two forms ( Main form and About form). the About form opens by a button click in the main form. The problem is that when I try to close the About form through the Control box or by using a button inside it `About.ActiveForm.Close()` it automatically closes all the Forms. I tried `About.ActiveForm.Hide()` and also doesn't work. Also, I tried to link the Cancel Button of the about form to that button and it didn't work.

Code of initiating the About form

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    About abt = new About();
    abt.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Code of Closing the About Form

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();   
}
```

I also tried this for the closing part

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();   
}
```

and I tried this also for the initiating part

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    About abt = new About();
    abt.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: You need to close the instance of About form, not current.

Comment: How can I achieve that?